# Python folium - if for popup doesn't work as expected

Tags: python, folium

I would like to customize one of my variables by styling it with a different color.

I tried to make the IF statement, but unfortunately, it doesn't work as expected.

```
 df = pd.read_csv("or_geo.csv")

 fo=folium.FeatureGroup(name="OR",overlay = True)

 for i,row in df.iterrows():
    lat =df.at[i, 'lat']
    lng = df.at[i, 'lng']
    sp = df.at[i, 'sp']
    stat = df.at[i,'status']
    popup = df.at[i,'sp'] +'<br>' + str(df.at[i, 'street']) + '<br>' + str(df.at[i, 'post code']) + '<br>' + stat

    if stat =="To be surveyed":
         '<strong style="text-transform:uppercase; color:red;">' + str(df.at[i,'status']) +'</strong>'

    elif stat =="Survey arranged":
        '<strong style="text-transform:uppercase; color:blue;">' + str(df.at[i,'status']) +'</strong>'

    else:
        '<strong style="text-transform:uppercase; color:green;">' + str(df.at[i,'status']) +'</strong>'
    
    fo.add_child(folium.Marker(location=[lat,lng], popup=popup, icon = 
    folium.Icon(color='blue', icon='glyphicon-calendar')))
    map.add_child(fo)
```

I have no errors, but I have no results either, as my font still comes default

The data looks like this:

[image]

[image]

**UPDATE:**

After applying

```
  popup = df.at[i,'sp'] +'<br>' + str(df.at[i, 'street']) + '<br>' + str(df.at[i, 'post code']) + '<br>' .format(row[stat], style)
```

I've noticed, that Python throws the Key error referring to the very first record in the 'status' row in my .csv file.

I am getting error:
***Key error: 'To be surveyed'***

which corresponds to the value in my row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is achieved by adding the variable of the result of the decision to the popup at the beginning of the loop process instead of making a conditional decision in the folium settings. Since no data was presented, I created the code by quoting sample data from other visualization libraries. And the group name needs to have a different name.

UPDATED:

```
import folium
import pandas as pd
import random

lat=[38.91427,38.91538,38.91458,38.92239,38.93222,38.90842,
     38.91931,38.93260,38.91368,38.88516,38.921894,38.93206,38.91275]

lon=[-77.02827,-77.02013,-77.03155,-77.04227,-77.02854,-77.02419,
     -77.02518,-77.03304,-77.04509,-76.99656,-77.042438,-77.02821,-77.01239]

street = ['PO Box 398 Buckland AK', '344 Watermelon St Holland Patnt NY', '162 Lime Ln #756 Aurora CO',
          'PO Box 57 Alba MI', '185 Apple Blvd Burnett IN', 'PO Box 157 Hoytville OH','PO Box 184 Burnside PA',
          '991 Watermelon Blvd #170 Memphis TN', '795 Papaya Ct #317 Parc Palenque PR2', 
          '646 Papaya Ctr #331 Urb Lirios Del Sur PR', 'PO Box 44 Marshfield MA','398 Cherry Dr #924 Toledo OR',
          '730 Lime Ctr Rogers OH']

status = random.choices(['To be surveyed','Survey arranged','Survey Complete'], k=13)

post_code = [99727, 13354, 80047, 49611, 47805, 43529, 15721, 38115, 617, 716, 2059, 97391, 44455]

sp = ['OR']*13

df = pd.DataFrame({'sp':sp, 'street': street, 'post_code': post_code, 'status': status, 'lat': lat, 'lng': lon})

df.head()

    sp  street  post_code   status  lat     lng
0   OR  PO Box 398 Buckland AK  99727   Survey Complete     38.91427    -77.02827
1   OR  344 Watermelon St Holland Patnt NY  13354   To be surveyed  38.91538    -77.02013
2   OR  162 Lime Ln #756 Aurora CO  80047   Survey arranged     38.91458    -77.03155
3   OR  PO Box 57 Alba MI   49611   Survey Complete     38.92239    -77.04227
4   OR  185 Apple Blvd Burnett IN   47805   Survey Complete     38.93222    -77.02854
```

**Data acquisition using itertools**

```
# Use itertools
for i,row in df.iterrows():
    print(type(row))
    print(row['sp'])
    print(row['street'])
    print(row['post_code'])
    print(row['status'])
    print(row['lat'])
    print(row['lng'])

<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
OR
PO Box 398 Buckland AK
99727
Survey Complete
38.91427
-77.02827
```

**Data acquisition using df.at[].**

```
# Use df.at[]
for i in range(len(df)):
    print(type(df.at[i,'sp']))
    print(df.at[i,'sp'])
    print(df.at[i,'street'])
    print(df.at[i,'post_code'])
    print(df.at[i,'status'])
    print(df.at[i,'lat'])
    print(df.at[i,'lng'])
<class 'str'>
OR
PO Box 398 Buckland AK
99727
Survey Complete
38.91427
-77.02827
```

**Use Itertools Full code**

```
fo = folium.Map(location=[df['lat'].mean(),df['lng'].mean()], zoom_start=14)

fg = folium.FeatureGroup(name="OR", overlay=True)

for i in range(len(df)):
    lat =df.at[i, 'lat']
    lng = df.at[i, 'lng']
    sp = df.at[i, 'sp']
    stat = df.at[i,'status']
    if stat =="To be surveyed":
        style = '<strong style="text-transform:uppercase; color:red;">' + stat +'</strong>'
    elif stat =="Survey arranged":
        style = '<strong style="text-transform:uppercase; color:blue;">' + stat +'</strong>'
    else:
        style = '<strong style="text-transform:uppercase; color:green;">' + stat +'</strong>'
    popup = df.at[i,'sp'] +'<br>' + df.at[i,'street'] + '<br>' + str(df.at[i,'post_code']) + '<br>{}' .format(style)
    folium.Marker(
        location=[lat, lng],
        icon=folium.Icon(color='blue', icon='glyphicon-calendar'),
        popup=popup
    ).add_to(fg)
    
fg.add_to(fo)
folium.LayerControl().add_to(fo)    

fo
```

**Use df.at[]**

```
fo = folium.Map(location=[df['lat'].mean(),df['lon'].mean()], zoom_start=14)

fg = folium.FeatureGroup(name="OR", overlay=True)

for i,row in df.iterrows():
    stat = row['status']
    if stat == 'To be surveyed':
        style = '<strong style="text-transform:uppercase; color:blue;">' + stat +'</strong>'
    elif stat == 'Survey arranged':
        style = '<strong style="text-transform:uppercase; color:red;">' + stat +'</strong>'
    else:
        style = '<strong style="text-transform:uppercase; color:green;">' + stat +'</strong>'
    popup = row['sp'] +'<br>' + row['street'] + '<br>' + str(row['post_code']) + '<br>{}'.format(style)
    
    folium.Marker(
        location=[row['lat'], row['lon']],
        icon=folium.Icon(color='blue', icon='glyphicon-calendar'),
        popup=popup
    ).add_to(fg)

fg.add_to(fo)
folium.LayerControl().add_to(fo)    

fo
```

[image]

Comment: Basically, the data was provided by the .csv file Do I need to list it in the code then?

It doesn't work unfortunately.

Comment: Since the data was not presented to me, I am looking for it myself and using the data in list format as a data frame. I am doing the same thing you are dataframing from a csv file. Have you tried my code? If you have sample data you can post, I'll modify the code based on that.

Comment: OK, I've updated the query where you can see my .csv file snippet. Would you be able to reproduce something in this document or explain to me what am I missing here? Thank you in advance.

Comment: The error is caused by `row['status']` or `df.at[i,'status']`, not `row[stat]`. Or it could be `row[stat[0]]`. print(type(stat)) will refer to the type of the variable. Since it is probably a series, you would need `[0]` to access the value.
Why use df.at[] when you are using iterrows? Your code needs to be consistent.

Comment: No, it doesn't work. When [0] is applied, then my Key error picks up the very first letter from the first input.

Comment: Have you tried all the others? If you use `row[stat.values[0]]`, do you not get the values correctly?

Comment: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'values'  this is what I am getting right now

Comment: Check the value and type of the stat variable in the loop process. `for i,row in df.iterrows(): .....stat = df.at[i,'status'];print(type(stat));print(stat);print(row['status'])`

Comment: I am running out of ideas. Would you be able to help me with the data snippet provided?

Comment: I changed the sample data to be closer to your data and rewrote the code using two methods: `iterrows` and `df.at[]`. The popup is set after the style conditionals and set to folium. Updated code and graphs.